# How do I escape Unicode espaces in Python strings without relying on r""?

Tags: python, windows, unicode, filesystems

Is there a function or a class that would let me escape unicode string literals like "\u" in path names?

I alread use r"c:\Users\myuser\somefile" or double slashes. But I do not like how it looks in my code, so I prefer to use a Python function or a lib to handle that because I do not always have straight strings assigments like that in my data, and my scripts tend to deal with user directories all the time.

thanks

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about where these strings are coming from. String literals are one of the few cases where any sort of escaping is necessary. If your strings *aren't* coming from string literals in your source code, you probably don't need to do escaping.

Comment: I am querying applications like Blender for user folder, or file paths etc, or some preferences from an addon or file path preferences from Blender etc. So yes I do not have a straight editable text always.

Comment: You don't need to worry about it except in string literals

Comment: For string literals, you can use `os.path.normpath('C:/Users/myuser/somefile')` or Python 3's `pathlib.Path('C:/Users/myuser/somefile')`. Either way ensures the path will use the proper backslash separator.

Comment: @eryksun regular slashes is not the issue, it is the windows paths that is the issue. I am asking how to normalize without any intervention (like adding r, b etc infront of the string path) of "c:\users\myuser\somefile", as you see nomatter how you skin the path it will just gave you will throw an error because of "\u" in the path on Windows.

Comment: The string literal creates a string at compile time. There's no bypassing backslash escapes without either using a raw string or escaping the backslashes. My workaround was for you to use forward slashes in your string literals and pass that to `normpath`. There is no more problem after that, and if you think there is, you're either misunderstanding something or not explaining the real problem clearly.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for the reply, that is clear to me now